# oracle full text not eliminating stopwords while creating inverted index

Tags: oracle, full-text-search

I intend to use oracle full text search. I am using oracle 12c and 11g. It seems, full text search does not filter out stopwords while creating inverted index. Also, it does not perform stemming.

```
create table text_demo (id number primary key, name varchar2(100), description varchar2(4000));

insert into text_demo (id, name, description) values( 1, 'Mike', 'Mike lives in Maryland and attended college at James Madison University');
insert into text_demo (id, name, description) values( 2, 'Joel', 'Joel lives in Ohio and attended college at The Ohio State University');

commit;

create index text_demo_idx1 on text_demo(description) indextype is ctxsys.context;

--searching for word phrase
select * from text_demo where contains( description, 'lives in ohio') > 0;
--1 record returned,as expected

select * from text_demo where contains( description, 'lives ohio') > 0;
--0 record returned. expected 1 record

select * from text_demo where contains( description, 'live in ohio') > 0;
--0 record returned. expected 1 record, lives should stem to live
```

please let me know if I am missing something or do i need to enable some feature explicitly

Answer (score 0):

The `$` operator is the stemming operator, use it in conjunction with `&` to conduct a phrase:

```
select * from text_demo where contains(description, '$live & $in & $ohio') > 0
```